# linq2db bulkcopyasync without error but no data inserted in the database

Tags: linq2db

I am using `linq2db` .NET Core library to bulk insert a collection. This  code can be executed without error but there is no data in the database. There are 2000 person object in persons list object. Person object has already identity in it.

```
using (var db = SqlServerTools.CreateDataConnection(connstring)
{
    await db.BulkCopyAsync(new BulkCopyOptions { KeepIdentity = true, TableName = "[Persons].[Person]" }, persons);
}
```

`Person` table in in `Persons` schema.

I have also tried with `BulkCopy` which can be executed without exception but still nothing in the database.

Some troubleshooting done:

- If my table is without any schema, it works. I can execute without exception and in the database I can see the data.
- But if my table is with schema, I can execute it without exception but in the database, I cannot see the data.

Model with Schema

```
[Table("Person", Schema = "Persons")]
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Model without Schema

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

What have I miss out? How to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Could you please try non async version of BulkCopy?

Comment: And why you have specified TableName? Also there is SchemaName, so TableName should not contain any quotes and schema.

Comment: If I just put `TableName = "Person"`, I get error "Cannot access destination table '[Person]'. I tried with non async but still no data in the database after executed

Comment: Ok, you have used function outside EF, so linq2db do not know how to map to objects to database. linq2db has own mapping - you have use them in that case. But better `ctx.BulkCopy`

Comment: I also used db.BulkCopy. I can execute without error but no data in the database.

Comment: First time i hear that BulkCopy have not inserted data. What shown in log?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, if my table does not have schema, the execution works and I can see the data in the database. Will your library works for schema?

Comment: It should work. EF integration should read schema info from Model. Also BulkCopyOptions have SchemaName property and a lot of other tweaks.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, have you tested your library with Schema in SQL Server database? I have posted my code for the model. Even my model is just one column, with schema, I can't see the save saved in the database.

Comment: For sure we have tested that with SQL Server. We have full CI cycle which runs about 400K tests. Check maybe you have started transaction and not committed and changes just rolled back.